# Measure distance using echo signal from Ultrasonic sensor

Tags: c, raspberry-pi

I was not happy with original code for [Ultrasonic sensor](https://github.com/sunfounder/SunFounder_SensorKit_for_RPi2/blob/master/C/25_ultrasonic_ranging/ultrasonic_ranging.c) and decided to write my own implementation.

I managed to do this, but it still looks weird. Could you help me to improve it?

```
#include <wiringPi.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

#define Trig    0
#define Echo    1

double raw_ultrasonic_measure(int trig, int echo) {
  digitalWrite(Trig, LOW);
  delayMicroseconds(1);

  digitalWrite(Trig, HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(10);
  digitalWrite(Trig, LOW);

  while(!(digitalRead(Echo) == 1));
  int time1 = micros();

  while(!(digitalRead(Echo) == 0));
  int time2 = micros();
  return (double)(time2 - time1) / 100;
}

double ultrasonic_measure(int trig, int echo) {
  double value1 = raw_ultrasonic_measure(trig, echo);
  delay(1);
  double value2 = raw_ultrasonic_measure(trig, echo);
  delay(1);
  double value3 = raw_ultrasonic_measure(trig, echo);
  delay(1);
  double value4 = raw_ultrasonic_measure(trig, echo);
  delay(1);
  double value5 = raw_ultrasonic_measure(trig, echo);
  return (value1 + value2 + value3 + value4 + value5) / 5;
} 

int main(void) {
  wiringPiSetup();
  pinMode(Echo, INPUT);
  pinMode(Trig, OUTPUT);

  while(1){
    double value = raw_ultrasonic_measure(Trig, Echo);
    printf("%0.1f cm\n", value);
    delay(1000);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**`raw_ultrasonic_measure`** measures the duration of an echo staying *high*. It is not related to the distance in any way, it is just a duration of trig signal.

You need a time elapsed from the beginning of a signal to reception of echo - that is, a duration of echo being *low*.

In a quick and dirty way,

```
        signal_start = micros();
        digitalWrite(Trig, HIGH);

        while (digitalRead(Echo) == 0) {
            ;
        }

        echo_received = micros();
        digital_write(Trig, LOW);

        return (echo_received - signal_start) / (2 * speed_of_sound);
```

In a real world application you would want to debounce echo, provide for a timeout, etc.

You may also want to account for the time taken by a first call to `digitalWrite`, but I doubt it will make any perceptible difference.

---

**`ultrasonic_measure`** is in fact a loop:

```
        double value = 0.0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            value += raw_ultrasonic_measure(Trig, Echo);
        }
        return value / 5;
```

One benefit of such approach is an ability to pass a number of samples as a parameter.

Comment: I love your implementation of ultrasonic_measure and clarification of raw_ultrasonic_measure, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

## Oops...

```
#define Trig    0
//      ^                                             !!!
#define Echo    1

double raw_ultrasonic_measure(int trig, int echo) {
  //                              ^                   !!!
  digitalWrite(Trig, LOW);
  //           ^                                      !!!
  delayMicroseconds(1);
  // ...
```

Look at the capitalization.  Your `trig` (and `echo`) function parameters are completely unused.  **That's why you `#define` constants to be ALL UPCASE normally.**

## Naming

Functions are usually named for what they *do*: "erase" something, "sort" some elements, "activate" some timer, ...

`ultrasonic_measure` (and it's `raw` variant) don't follow this style.  They name what they return, not what they *do* in order to be able to return that value.  How about `measure_ultrasonic_distance`? (measure used as a verb then.)

Answer (score 4):

Take these comments *together with* the comments of others, not *instead of* them. They have already said much that needs saying.

```
double raw_ultrasonic_measure(int trig, int echo) {
  digitalWrite(Trig, LOW);
  delayMicroseconds(1);

  digitalWrite(Trig, HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(10);
  digitalWrite(Trig, LOW);
```

The 5 lines above are basically a "ping" operation - you are generating a sonar ping and shaping it using the 1 and 10 constants. I'd suggest you write a parameterized `ultrasonic_ping(duration)` function.

```
  while(!(digitalRead(Echo) == 1));
  int time1 = micros();

  while(!(digitalRead(Echo) == 0));
  int time2 = micros();
  return (double)(time2 - time1) / 100;
}
```

I find your while loops difficult to read and comprehend. Please consider changing to something more left-to-right, and more explicit, like:

```
while (digitalRead(Echo) != 0) 
    EMPTY();
```

Finally, what does `1` mean? What does `0` mean when returned by `digitalRead(Echo)`? Could you use `HIGH` or `LOW` there? Or some other constant?

Why do you divide your time intervals by 100? Is that the speed of sound in microseconds per centimeter? A nice constant would help...

Comment: 100 is experimentally found value, probably I need better idea.

Comment: Your suggestion for the empty while loop makes things more unreadable, now somebody reading the code has to guess that `EMPTY()` does nothing, rather than seeing an empty loop body.

Comment: You could use `/*EMPTY*/` instead. Or `{}`. Anything to make clear what's happening.